# OpenNMS, NSClient++ (x64), Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, opennms, nsclient++

I've installed OpenNMS, and configured NSClient++ on a Win2k8 r2 box. NMS sees the NSClient, however nsclient logs the following errors:

- error:../../include\Socket.h:649: Error: Could not complete SSL handshake : [-1] 1, attempting to resume...

I've tried everything imaginable to resolve this issue, along with disabling SSL, which nets another error:

- Could not read a full NRPE packet from socket, only got: 53

Does anyone have any helpful tips on getting this to install and work correctly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one i got too, but on my side it doesn't give much problems.
The other one, try to increase some timeouts:

command_timeout = 60
socket_timeout = 50

Which check are trying to execute on windows side?
Maybe check logs?